# Unable to set date/time in past (Gentoo)

Tags: linux, time, date

I have a Gentoo-based server (with OpenRC) running on physical hardware.

Today, I have noticed the time was 3 minutes in future despite ntpd running all the time. So I shut down ntpd and tried fixing it both with `ntpdate` and by manually running `date -s`. Neither seems to change the time despite reporting no failures.

I got upset and tried changing the date one year into future. That worked, but now I cannot get back into year 2017:

```
zeus linux # date --set 2017-05-02
Mon May  1 00:00:00 CEST 2017
zeus linux # date
Wed May  2 09:11:49 CEST 2018
```

The kernel appears to silently ignore all `setdateofday()` or `clock_settime()` system calls that move time backwards. Running `hwclock --hctosys` also doesn't help, even though the hardware clock has the right time.

What is going on?